# Is string a number without using Execute()

Tags: string, numbers, maxscript

```
str = "92349"       
n = str as integer
if (n != undefined) then ...
```

Without using Execute(), is there a better way in MAXScript to determine whether a string represents a number (or doesn't)?

Comment: A string is never a number, a string can _represent_ a number.

Comment: I think your solution is just fine, n = str as integer. It will try to cast to integer and if it fails you'll get undefined. Do you have situation where this is not adequate enough?

Answer (score 2):

You can also try dotnet within max like so:

```
local pstring = "12"
local res = false
local parseRes = (dotnetclass "System.Int32").TryParse pstring &res

if parseRes do 
(
    print res
)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your .net solution is very cool. But why to avoid mxs simple way in one line

```
fn isInteger str = isKindOf (str as number) integer
```

Comment: In what ways is this a better way to determine whether a string represents a number?

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on the accepted answer, it's better to do it that way because of the way maxscript interprets various number types given there's a letter in them. As a result, all of the following would result in a number:

```
" " as number --> 0
"." as number --> 0.0
"L" as number --> 0L
"P" as number --> 0P
"f" as number --> 0f
"m" as number --> 0f
"t" as number --> 0f
```

or variations of these:

```
"ft" as number --> 0f
"fd0" as number --> 0f
"te0" as number --> 0f
"f00m" as number --> 0f
"m.f.t." as number --> 0f
etc.
```

Most of the time you will get zero – but not always, note for example this sequence (ASCII 185, 178, 179):

```
"¹" as number --> 137
"²" as number --> 130
"³" as number --> 131
```